# Magento 2.2.5 - How to increase the quality of product view photos JPG

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento-2.2.5, image-quality

I'm using Magento 2.2.5
How to increase the quality of product view photos JPG
Because in product view the JPG quality is not high, but link out to see the photo is high quality.
How to fix it?
Please help.

Comment: Maybe you change size of product pictures? Without regenerating pictures?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: my photo is 733,  in product view is 670 but quality is not high @BartZalas

Comment: please check @RohanHapani

Answer (score 2):

The quality of image is set in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image` at line no 39 **protected $_quality = 80;**

You can override this in you module.

File : CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Product\Image" />
</config>
```

File : CompanyName/ModuleName/Model/Product You can set the quality to which you want to set. Then flush image cache.

```
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Product;

class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_quality = 100;

        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: i already edited 'vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php' 
 but i dont understand File : CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml ? the path is ? @RohanHapani

Comment: What is your magento root path?

Comment: can you please mention folder name...which is into app/code/ ?

Comment: I made a module to make it easier to edit this value in the admin. See github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality. Just installing it will increase the quality to 85 but you can change it to whatever you want in the admin. Using 100 is actually not a good idea as it will greatly increase your file size and have no noticeable increase in quality from something more reasonable like 92.